# Mapping an Image on a Acrylic Glass Pane

Tags: materials, node-editor, glass

I managed to put an image onto a glass pane (using UV-mapping and nodes).

Following a tutorial on YouTube on acrylic glass, I was able to improved the pane (adding *Fresnel* to have the edges reflect).

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to add the image texture to the pane. The *Fresnel* is now blocking the port of the *Mix Shader* where my *Image Texture* used to go.

This is my node-setup:
[image: nodes-setup]

Using version 2.9.1.0 rendering with cycles.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Comment: that did the trick, thank you @susu !